# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str api vimeworld

Tags: python, python-3.x

пытаюсь взять информацию о уровне игрока, но получаю ошибку

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'https://api.vimeworld.ru/user/name/FQGM')
data = dict(json.loads(r.data))
print(data['level'])
input()
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было обращаться по числовому индексу, а уже потом обращаться к `level`:

```
print('Level:', data[0]['level'])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]